# Write \$V_{A}\$ in terms of \$V_{in}\$ and the resistor values algebraically in a Op-Amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

**Question**

Consider the Op-Amp circuit in Fig. Q1(a). Write \$V_{A}\$ in terms of \$V_{in}\$ and the resistor values algebraically.

[image]

---

**My Try**

- Case 1 :

  I see wire(+) as opened since it draw almost 0 current ideally. So, we have

$$V_A=V_{in}\left(\frac{R_3}{R_3+R_4}\right)$$

- Case 2 :

  Transform the circuit as if the following one. Since wire(+) and wire(-) ideally have no potential difference, I shorted them together.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4sh1f.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

$$
R_{13}=\left(\frac{1}{R1}+\frac{1}{R3}\right)^{-1}\space \space \space \space and\space \space \space \space R_{24}=\left(\frac{1}{R2}+\frac{1}{R4}\right)^{-1}
$$

$$
R_{eq}=R_{13}+R_{24}
$$

Therefore, 
$$
V_A=V_{in}\left(\frac{R_{13}}{R_{eq}}\right)
$$

---

**My Questions**

1. For Case 1 and Case 2, which one is correct? Or, both are wrong?
2. How to find the current I from \$V_{A}\$ to \$V_{out}\$? Can I calculate it from the following equation?

$$
I=\frac{0-V_A}{R_1}+\frac{V_{in}-V_A}{R_2}
$$

---

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You missed R5 and Vout in case 2

Comment: Oh~...If I include R5 and Vout in the circuit, it will become so complicated... :c

Answer (score 3):

Since the op-amp inputs are (ideally) open circuits, case 1 is correct.

Case 2 is wrong conceptually.  In the actual circuit, resistors \$R_3\$ and \$R_4\$ are series connected - *all* of the current through \$R_4\$ is through \$R_3\$.

However, in your case 2 schematic, this is not the case; there can be a non-zero current through the wire connected the two resistor branches.

Consider the following instead:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv0ToJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now, this gives the same result as case 1.